# Run multiple Google MLKit TextRecognition processes in parallel

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I try to make multiple MLKit TextRecognition processes run in multiple threads with the code below:

```java
private TextRecognizer client;
private Executor mExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

private void init() {
    TextRecognizerOptions build = new TextRecognizerOptions.Builder()
                .setExecutor(mExecutor)
                .build();
    client = TextRecognition.getClient(build);
//  client = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
}

private void testTextRec() {
    new Thread(new RecRunnable("task 1")).start();
    new Thread(new RecRunnable("task 2")).start();
    new Thread(new RecRunnable("task 3")).start();
    new Thread(new RecRunnable("task 4")).start();
}

private class RecRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String name;
    private RecRunnable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bitmap bitmap = readFromAsset("huchuan_passport.jpg");
        InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, "start " + name + " at :" + start);
        client.process(inputImage)
              .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(Text text) {
                      long elapse = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                      Log.e(TAG, name + " elapses: " + elapse + "ms");
                  }
              }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  }
              });
    }

    private Bitmap readFromAsset(String fileName) {
        try {
            InputStream open = getAssets().open(fileName);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also try the default Options `client = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);` and running the demo on device with 8 processors.

According to the log, four tasks cannot work in parallel.

```
2022-12-27 10:11:31.843 30756-30756/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: available processors : 4
2022-12-27 10:11:32.181 30756-30810/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: start task 1 at :1672107092181
2022-12-27 10:11:32.212 30756-30812/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: start task 3 at :1672107092212
2022-12-27 10:11:32.270 30756-30811/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: start task 2 at :1672107092270
2022-12-27 10:11:32.281 30756-30813/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: start task 4 at :1672107092281
2022-12-27 10:11:33.490 30756-30756/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: task 1 elapses: 1309ms
2022-12-27 10:11:34.378 30756-30756/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: task 3 elapses: 2166ms
2022-12-27 10:11:35.215 30756-30756/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: task 2 elapses: 2945ms
2022-12-27 10:11:36.022 30756-30756/com.pax.tstmlkit E/MainActivity: task 4 elapses: 3741ms
```

Does anybody know how to make multiple MLKit TextRecognition processes run in parallel?

Comment: Quick comment. Normally in a multi-threaded system one must prioritize the threads. I'll explain later.

Comment: No explanation but clarifying questions.  A task is a thread, so why do you launch 4 runnables, instead of directly launching the 4 tasks? The tasks are launched in sequence, one at a time, so they cannot work in parallel. Since you mention 8 processors, is the objective of the code to launch up to 8 tasks in sequence and have these tasks be processed in "parallel" (one task/one processor)?

Comment: I understand that you raised the question one level up to the runnable scheduler. I suggest you read the chapter 11 of the Java - The Complete Reference doc for a better understanding of the multi-threaded system.